# Unable to map Varchar(50) to string type using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am using dapper to map tables to C# objects,
My Table name is **'ProductCatagory'** and there is only one column named 'CatagoryCode' and the data type is varchar(50).
I have also a class named ***'ProductCatagory'*** with property of string type named 'CotagoryCode'.

```
public class ProductCatagory
{
    public string CatagoryCode { get; set; }
}
```

The query statement is `connection.QueryAsync<ProductCatagory>("Select CatagoryCode From ProductCatagory", new{}, CommandType.Text);`

Every time I tried to execute the query statement, I get the following error.

```
System.Data.DataException: 'Error parsing column 0 (CatagoryCode=Battery - String)'
```

if I change the query to

`connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>("Select CatagoryCode From ProductCatagory", new{}, CommandType.Text);`

the query works fine.

Comment: Prolly you have another ProductCatagory where offended property is not a string... In other case it should works fine (or there is a typo)

Comment: I assume you have typos somewhere since you have spelled "category" in two different and incorrect ways in this question alone.

Comment: @DavidG,It is CatagoryCode,and ProductCatagory, Does it also check for grammar?

Comment: `CotagoryCode` there is your issue. You have a typo.

Comment: @mjwills, "CotagoryCode" why?

Comment: You tell me - it is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume correct spelling all the way from the database to the c# code. Otherwise it gets too confusing. Thus your entity class is this:

```cs
public class ProductCategory
{
    public string CategoryCode
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

And then there is no reason this shouldn't work:

```cs
connection.QueryAsync<ProductCategory>("Select CategoryCode From ProductCategory");
```

When you pass `new{}` you pass a empty dynamic object. That parameter is only for queries with parameters in it. And `CommandType.Text` is default, so no need to pass that either.